# How to get a jQuery data variable into a button not div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a rails site that uses jquery. I am moving my "follow" button from a user's page to a search display page.

This means that I have to change the javascript from javascript that assumes that there is just one follow button on each a page to javascript that works with many follow buttons on a page. Each of these buttons is for a different user in the search results.

My old code worked like this:

HTML:

```
= content_tag 'div', id: 'friends-data', data: {user_id: current_user.id, friend_id: user.id, is_following: true } do
= button_tag "Follow", class: 'btn btn-Follow followUser'
```

HTML (compiled):

```
<div id="friends-data" data-user-id="2" data-friend-id="8" data-is-following="true"></div>
<button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-follow followUser">Follow</button>
```

JS:

```
this.data = $('#friends-data').data();
```

I hope to have the button have its own data. This way my this.data will already be the data and I wont have to grab it from the div above it. That way the JS wont always grab the data from the first users, but it will grab the data concerning the user affiliated with the button.

My issue is that `this.data = $(this).data();` does not work.

For instance given:

```
<div id="friends-data" data-user-id="2" data-friend-id="8" data-is-following="true"></div>
<button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-follow followUser" data-user-id="2" data-friend-id="8" data-is-following="true">Follow</button>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".followUser").click(function(){
    window.alert($('#friends-data').data());
    window.alert(this.data());
  });
});
```

This prints the first alert but not the second.

Comment: `this` is different than `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this :

```
window.alert(this.data());
```

with this :

```
window.alert($(this).data());
```